# How were Doctor Arik Soong and Noonien Soong related?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, star-trek-data, star-trek-enterprise

I see Noonien listed as a descendant of Arik, but I'm not exactly sure how they are related.

Is there a Soong family tree of some sort that shows who married who, the name of the offspring, etc. that shows the relation?

Noonien isn't one of Arik's augments, is he?

I can't find a record of Arik having a wife or children of his own.

If there's any writer's notes or manuals that explain this that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi. I note you haven't accepted any answers for this question yet. If my answer addresses the question, would you please consider answering it for future viewers? If not, please let me know where I can improve it!

Answer (score 4):

Considering my namesake is involved, I'd better take this question!

According to the [Memory Beta page on Arik Soong](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Arik_Soong), it is explained that he was **Noonien Soong's *great-grandfather***:

> In [The Worst of Both Worlds](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Worst_of_Both_Worlds), the mirror universe version of Noonien
>   Soong told Jean-Luc Picard that Arik Soong was his **great-grandfather**,
>   *indicating that the same filial relationship existed between Arik and
>   Noonien Soong in the primary universe*. Furthermore, the fact that the
>   mirror Arik Soong was executed in 2155, as depicted in the novel [Age
>   of the Empress](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Age_of_the_Empress), would seem to indicate that he had fathered at least
>   one child in both universes by that time.
>
> Noonien Soong may have been named out of admiration that Arik had for Khan Noonien

Now, either way it means that Noonien himself wasn't an augment, but *potentially* was the offspring of one of Arik's augments; the details just aren't there I'm afraid!  Bear in mind that this is all out of canon.

Comment: Is there anything more? It just seems weird that he considered his offspring to be the Augments and not actual biological offspring. By the way I love Enterprise. Never watched it before but the Xindi theme was awesome.

Comment: @JMFB that's all that's mentioned on the MB page I've linked to above.  The MA page indicates that Arik raised the Augments as his offspring.

Comment: There's nothing better that one could hope for than an answer from @N_Soong himself! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I personally liked the idea of Arik Soong trying to reach Klach D'kel Brakt, which he called the Briar Patch in the ENT episode The Augments.
We all know there's a special planet located in the Briar Patch since Insurrection.
So at some time after serving his prison penalty he actually could have travelled to the Ba'ku planet, rejuvenating and starting to do the theoretical work on cybernetics like he indicated at the end of The Augments for the next like 200 years.
This could also be the reason why the Ba'ku have the knowledge about positronic technology.
So my idea is Arik Soong and Noonian Soong are the same person.
He may have left Ba'ku for the same reason as the Son'a, not agreeing to their no-technology-lifestyle and starting the practical work on cybernetics on Omicron Theta and building the first androids.
He may have changed his name, because he thought people still remember Arik Soong as a criminal and doesn't want his cybernetic work being remembered the same way his augment work is remembered.

Comment: His quip at the end of one of the ENT episodes "I was thinking about trying cybernetics" or something makes sense in this light.